# Mathjax curly brackets don't show up (using jekyll)

Tags: math, latex, jekyll, mathjax

I use **Mathjax** on my static (jekyll-generated) site : Mathjax is loaded but curly brackets don't show up.

```
$ \{ 2*3 \} $ -> 2*3
$ \left{ 2*3 \right} -> \left{ 2*3 \right} (math style)
```

I'd like to have (for instance) a simple `{2*3}`

Cheers

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK found out :

You have to **escape the backslash** because there seems to be 2 levels of interpretation : jekyll then mathjax. So you need to escape the backslash from Jekyll so it renders for Mathjax to escape the bracket :

```
$ \\{ 2*3 \\} $ -> {2*3}
```

Comment: You can also try to wrap it into 
{%raw%} ... {%endraw%} which might be more readable

Comment: You do not necessarily have to escape anything. By default, Jekyll uses kramdown which has built-in support for LaTeX-like input (though somewhat unusually uses $$ to delimit both inline and block-level math), see https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks.

Comment: Using two backslashes works for MathJax, but then it doesn't work for LaTeX anymore if I want to convert the same source file to PDF. Is there a way to convert the same source file to both HTML with MathJax, and PDF for such simple things?

Comment: I would like a best practice answer to weibeld's last question.

Comment: My own solution: Use Pandoc with
  header-includes: \def\set#1{{\left\{#1\right\}}}
in the Yaml front matter.
Then use MathJax with
    TeX: {
      Macros: {
        set: ["{\\left\\{ #1 \\right\\}}", 1]
      }
    }
in the Hub Config. Then use \set{} everywhere.

Comment: This also works if using Hugo instead of Jekyll.

Comment: I had to use the `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` to keep it a valid LaTex and a proper github page display.